# Set environment variable for use with getenv (not GetEnvironmentVariable)

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I have a DLL obtaining startup options using `getenv` (`<stdlib.h>`) call. I would like to set that variable in the same process, before opening the DLL, so that it is accessible via `getenv`. Which function should I use to set it?

I learned that there are two sets of env vars under windows: one is manipulated via win32 API (GetEnvironemntVariable, SetEnvironmentVariable), another one can be read using `getenv`, and probably set via [_putenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zh4e6k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), is that the one I should use?

Is this function accessible from python, perhaps via ctypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current ~VS2019 situation *appears* to be:

- The calls to the `getenv` function retrieve the values from a block the MS CRT initializes at load time.
- Calls to `GetEnvironmentVariable` retrieve the value from the process environment block.
- Calls to `SetEnvironmentVariable` update *only* the value from the process environment block. These changes will *not* be seen by `getenv`.
- Calls to `putenv` update *both* the value in the CRT block *and* also additionally call Win32 `SetEnvironmentVariable` to update the [process environment block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables).

So, actually regardless of what you use it for:

- Use `_wputenv_s` to set the env var - it will update both.
- Use `::GetEnvironmentVariableW` to read: It will read from the environment block, which will contain the value regardless of which method was used.

### Regarding `getenv`

If the code using `getenv` is using the same MS CRT that your code -- that is, the code is dynamically linked to the CRT and actually uses the same version as you, then you can always use `putenv`.

If the DLL (AND its CRT) is dynamically or delay-loaded and you are able to call `putenv` before the dll is loaded, then you can use it.

(This is conjecture, I have not tested this exactly:) If the DLL is already loaded in you process and it uses a statically linked CRT, or another CRT than the one you are using, than the environment data for **its** `getenv` call is already loaded up, an nothing that you do on your side of the DLL boundary will change that. Out of luck in this case I guess.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv?view=msvc-170
- https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4774
- https://blogs.msmvps.com/senthil/2009/10/13/when-what-you-set-is-not-what-you-get-setenvironmentvariable-and-getenv/

Answer (score 1):

As the question is tagged with Python, the blessed way to manage environment variables in Python is to update the `os.environ` mapping.

Because the doc for `os.putenv()` says:

> Assignments to items in os.environ are automatically translated into corresponding calls to putenv(); however, calls to putenv() don’t update os.environ, so it is actually preferable to assign to items of os.environ.

Comment: Fascinating. So in Python on Windows we have 3 layers os.environ -> mscrt envorinment data -> Win32 Process Env Block. :-D